# Select Md5 combination of 2 rows from mysql

Tags: codeigniter

I have md5 some of the user information (lets say id and email for simplicity) and would like to use those information to find that user in my database.

The code in it's simplest form looks something like this

```
return $this->db->get_where('table', array('MD5(id,email)='=>$token ) ,1);
```

Not sure why but its returning false;

**Update: trying to do this in sql**

Just found out in when i try to do this in mysql I get an error

```
#1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'md5'
```

*Is this mean you cant md5 multiple rows ? if so how do I do this!*

**Update: Again it returns false**

```
$this->db->select('md5(id,email) as token');
$this->db->where('token', $token);
$this->db->limit(1);
$result = $this->db->get('table->customers');
```

Comment: The MD5 function requires one input string as a parameter, and MySQL sees it as you passing 2.  I'm commenting this rather than an answer because I can't test it at the moment, but you could try `MD5(CONCAT(id, email))` as the `concat()` will produce a single string.  How well it works in practice is another matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try concat in the where clause.

```
$this->db->where("md5(CONCAT(id,email)) = '".$token."'");
```